# 画像をプログラムに読み込ませて種類を判別するためのラベル付けで詰まりました

Tags: python

保存された画像をプログラムに読み込ませ、「その画像が車か電車か船か」を判別するためのラベル付けで詰まりました。プログラムを実行すると、以下のエラーが表示されてしまいます。

全くの初心者なのでわからないですが、自分の打ったもの（書籍の丸写し）が違うというより環境が整ってないということでエラーが出てしまったのかなと思いました。
ご回答よろしくお願いします。参考書籍は「稼ぐAI」というものです。

**プログラム**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

image_list = []
label_list = []

basedir='./data/'
label_name=['car','train','ship']

traindir=basedir + 'training/'

for dir in os.listdir(traindir):
    if dir == '.DS_Store':
        continue

    dir1 = traindir + dir
    label = 0

    if dir == label_name[0]:
        label = 0
    elif dir == label_name[1]:
        label = 1
    elif dir == label_name[2]:
        label = 2

    for file in os.listdir(dir1):
        if file != '.DS_Store':
            label_list.append(label)
            filepath = dir1 + '/' + file
            image = np.array(Image.open(filepath).convert('RGB').resize((100, 100)))
            image_list.append(image / 255.)

X = np.array(image_list)
Y = to_categorical(label_list)
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

~\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: DLL load failed: ダイナミック リンク ライブラリ (DLL) 初期化ルーチンの実行に失敗しました。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-fc06df009de9> in <module>
----> 1 from keras.models import Sequential
      2 from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten
      3 from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
      4 from keras.optimizers import Adam
      5 import numpy as np

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py in <module>
      4 from . import data_utils
      5 from . import io_utils
----> 6 from . import conv_utils
      7 
      8 # Globally-importable utils.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py in <module>
      7 from six.moves import range
      8 import numpy as np
----> 9 from .. import backend as K
     10 
     11 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py in <module>
     87 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
     88     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
---> 89     from .tensorflow_backend import *
     90 else:
     91     # Try and load external backend.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in <module>
      3 from __future__ import print_function
      4 
----> 5 import tensorflow as tf
      6 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops as tf_ops
      7 from tensorflow.python.training import moving_averages

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     29 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     30 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: ダイナミック リンク ライブラリ (DLL) 初期化ルーチンの実行に失敗しました。


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: 参考にした書籍がある場合は(引用元として)書籍名も質問文に含めてあると親切かなと思います。後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて追記してみてください。

Comment: [類似のエラー](https://qiita.com/grinpeaceman/items/c55ab14d843828fa05ab)対策を行ったQiita記事では、tensorflowのバージョンを`1.12.0`で環境構築して解決しています。懸念されているようにtensorflowはOSや利用ライブラリで環境が大きく変わりますので、参考書籍にセットアップ手順が記載されている場合はバージョンも含めて同一の手順で構築されてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 返信遅くなり申し訳ありません、そしてご指摘ありがとうございます。cubickさん、書籍名を追加しました！payanecoさん、残念ながらバージョンは載ってないみたいです…